# How do I get the trackbar value?

Tags: c++, windows, trackbar

I feel a little silly asking this, seems pretty simple but I can't find the solution anywhere. 
I have a trackbar made in visual studio 2008 and I want to use it to adjust an image threshold but I can't find the code to retrieve the sliders/markers position.
Any help would be much appreciated and I am using C++

Comment: what library? what have you done so far? what is a trackbar?

Answer (score 1):

For raw Win32, send the trackbar a [`TBM_GETPOS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760189%28VS.85%29.aspx) message.

Trackbar messages:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff486075%28VS.85%29.aspx